# i have configured hadoop fully distributed mode it was working properly but after rebooting now my namenode is not getting started

Tags: hadoop

```
   <configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/abcd/name</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>/abcd/data1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

> bin/hadoop namenode -format 
>       bin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode

Error msg - 
logs:directory  /abcd/name is in an inconsistent state:storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.**

Answer (score 0):

Configuration properties used in your config file - dfs.name.dir,dfs.data.dir etc are deprecated from Hadoop2.0 onwards.

```
Hadoop-1.0 -> Hadoop2.0
dfs.name.dir  -> dfs.namenode.name.dir
dfs.data.dir -> dfs.datanode.data.dir
dfs.name.edits.dir ->  dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir
```

There might be files inside your hdfs name, data, checkpoint directories. Try to  delete the contents of data, name and checkpoint directories before formatting name node, HDFS formatting fails if there are hdfs specific files in the directories.

dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir - default location is /tmp/dfs/namesecondary

Comment: i am using hadoop 1.2.1

Comment: i have delete the directories that u have mentioned but after that again i formated still not getting start and also now datanode is also not starting

Comment: What is the error msg u r getting when u format namenode ?

Comment: You can start hdfs service only if the formatting is proper, otherwise hdfs daemons will not come up.

Comment: Did you followed any extra sets which are not mentioned in the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of namenode and datanode directories.